# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn't find "xxxxx.so" in android.tools.build:gradle 3.6.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-native-interface

I have a .aar including some native .so. Andrid project B implements this .aar like:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation(name: 'abcd', ext:'aar')
        implementation(name: 'somethingelse', ext:'aar')
    }
```

In Android project B, When I use android.tools.build:gradle 3.4.0 and 3.5.0, everything works fine. But When I change to 3.6.0 in the root gradle:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0' // dont work
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0' // works fine
    }
```

run time gives me errors like：

```
2021-05-24 20:41:55.723 6064-6153/com.xxxx.xxxxx A/xxxx: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.DexClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~tqEwSNB6cPXs4GapbzXZzQ==/com.xxxx.xxxxx-TRHmC-RfgNxXwoU9Ax-Hrw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~tqEwSNB6cPXs4GapbzXZzQ==/com.xxxx.xxxxx-TRHmC-RfgNxXwoU9Ax-Hrw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]] couldn't find "libcamera_lib.so"
java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:1083)
java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:1008)
java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:1664)
```

high lighting:

```
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~tqEwSNB6cPXs4GapbzXZzQ==/com.xxxx.xxxxx-TRHmC-RfgNxXwoU9Ax-Hrw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]] couldn't find "libcamera_lib.so"
```

but when I unzip and check the aar and even the final output apk, I do find that cmera_lib.so is right there.
[image: unzip apk]

Any idea about whats going on there? why change android.tools.build:gradle would cause .so not found error in run time and the .so is right inside the apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change that happened in 3.6.0 was that `android:extractNativeLibs` default [has changed](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs):

> The default value is "true" if extractNativeLibs is not configured in AndroidManifest.xml. However, when building your app using Android Gradle plugin 3.6.0 or higher, this property is reset to "false" if it is NOT configured in AndroidManifest.xml and minSdkVersion >= 23. If minSdkVersion < 23 and extractNativeLibs is explicitly set to "false" in AndroidManifest.xml, you must add the following to your app's build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> packagingOptions {
>   jniLibs {
>     useLegacyPackaging = false
>   }
> }
> ```

The problem is that [some devices (e.g. Xiaomi)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147096055) still don't support non-extracted native libraries.

Comment: thanks, I set it to android:extractNativeLibs=true, and problem solved